# Tagging files in macOs Finder... quickly

Tags: macos, bash, shell, macos-mojave

I'm looking to create keyboard shortcuts to tag files in the finder... without using Automator.  The goal is to *rapidly* quicklook and tag files.

I'm imagining:

```
cmd-opt-0 -> tags selected file "Category0"
cmd-opt-1 -> tags selected file "Category1" 
...
cmd-opt-9 -> tags selected file "Category9"
```

Approaches I've ruled out:

- **Shell script:** qlmanage is the quicklook command for the bash and it doesn't autoplay files.  This means I'd have to manually hit the play button
- **Applescript:** applescript quicklooks files via the shell
- **Automator** is, as mentioned, slow
- **a Tag... shortcut** this is the closest I've gotten but it requires me to cmd-ctrl-opt-T, type the tag, return, return

Comment: Keyboard Maestro or Alfred with a custom shell script? https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/1334-labelcolor-%E2%80%94-sets-a-label-color-for-selected-files-and-directories/ or https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/10258-convenient-way-to-tag-files-with-alfred/?tab=comments#comment-52112

Comment: Keyboard Maestro!!!!    Does it all AND lets me hit the down arrow to skip to the next item!  NOT BAD AT ALL!